# How to implement a media server for local music files on the phone in flutter that can be used by DLNA

Tags: flutter, dart, httpserver, upnp, dlna

I am working on a flutter app (for iOS and Android). One of the function of the app is to find DLNA renderes in the local network and allow user to play the local music files on his phone on these DLNA renderes. I have incorperated the [DART-DLNA package](https://github.com/succlz123/DLNA-Dart)in my app and am Able to list all DLNA-UPNP devices and I can send a url of a media to the selected DLAN renderer and it starts playing. I can also control the play/pause and stop functions. So far so good

[image]

Now I want to be able to play the music files that are on the device from this app. When working on ANdrodi native earlier I used [DroidUpnp](https://github.com/trishika/DroidUPnP)  which mainly uses [cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) and [nanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) libraries. Cling provides upnp stack and nanoHttpd is used for creating a webserver to server the media files. The DroidUpnp app lists the music content like this

[image]

On going depper when reached to the actual music file the app will send that file via upnp/dlna.

On Flutter I am not sure how to go for it? How to List those files and then get the files urls like `http://192.168.1.190:8192/a-24684.mp3` and send it to the render.